# What does the word "footlocker" mean in this context? Is this a slang word?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was watching this youtube video from some guy and he uses the word "**footlocker**" in this sentence:

> The reason no one ever shoehorned your shoe and unlaced it is because you got a **footlocker**.

I only know this meaning for this word:

> A trunk for storing personal belongings, especially one kept at the foot of a bed, as in a barracks. (source thefreedictionary.com)

This is the entire video and the part when he says the sentence above is at 03:30: [Ice Cube Is Getting Cancelled For This Blackface Reality Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ehpNjVkAAw&ab_channel=DavidLucas)

Comment: The meaning you mention, is the meaning of the word.  A small, often lockable, trunk.  *The reason no messed with your shoes is because you keep them locked up.*  If the clip says *because you **go to** Footlocker,* instead of, *because you **got a** footlocker,* then pboss3010's answer is the one you're looking for.  Contextually, however, *because you **got a** footlocker* makes perfect sense.

Comment: He says because you **go** to Footlocker, the store. He does not say "got".  But his articulation in the video at that point is not very clear. Footlocker sells sports shoes only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To expand a bit on pboss3010's answer: Here's the fuller context.

> REALITY-SHOW GUY: I've never in my life had— You know, they'll come out and *give* me my shoe. But I've never had anyone actually unlace it, open it, shoe-horn the back, and slide my foot into the shoe.
>
> COMMENTATOR: [...] And you know why no one has ever shoe-horned your shoe and unlaced it? — It's because you go to [Foot Locker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_Locker). You're over there [at Foot Locker] buying casual shoes. [But today] you were buying shoes that require a shoe horn. Ninety-nine percent of my shoes don't require a shoe horn. And I would say that, for most young black men, we wear a lot of sneakers. Or slip-ons. Or slides.

The context here is a reality show where black people get made up to pass as white. The guy in question was impressed that when he went to a shoe store, the salesman unlaced his shoe for him and helped him get it on. The critic is saying, "Dude. You didn't get pampered today because you looked *white*, you got pampered because that shoe store you were at wasn't a f--king Foot Locker."

Similarly, one might say "Oh, you got a tablecloth and nice silverware? The reason you've never gotten a tablecloth and nice silverware before is because you eat at McDonald's." Same vibe.

And in that sense, *yes*, "Foot Locker" here is slang, or at least something like a [metonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy): it's the name of a specific store, being used as a stand-in for an entire class of low-end sneaker stores, in the same way as "McDonald's" might stand in for an entire class of low-end fast-food restaurants.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like he's saying "because you go to Foot Locker". Foot Locker is a chain of shoe stores typically found in malls that mostly sells sneakers.

Answer (score 0):

He's talking about the differing levels of service in an expensive shoe store, where the attendant will actually put the shoe on your foot when you want to try it on, as compared to a more every-day store like [Foot Locker](https://www.footlocker.com/), where the attendant will just throw the box in your general direction.